# How do I partition this variable so that its cummulative total remain unchanged when filtering?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using `SQL Server 2012` and I have the following `T-SQL` query running against a table.

```
SELECT ID
       ,StayDate
       ,Dateadd(day, -datepart(day,StayDate) + 1, StayDate) as 'MonthOfStay'
       ,DailyRateAmount
       ,SUM(DailyRateAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS [CummulativeRateAmt]
FROM Table1
WHERE ID = 625
```

Output of above query is as follows:

```
ID     StayDate     MonthOfStay  DailyRateAmt CummulativeRateAmt
625    2018-09-28   2018-09-01    100              400
625    2018-09-29   2018-09-01    100              400
625    2018-09-30   2018-09-01    100              400
625    2018-10-01   2018-10-01    100              400
```

When I add a filter on the `StayDate` to this query, it gives me the following output:

```
SELECT ID
       ,StayDate
       ,Dateadd(day, -datepart(day,StayDate) + 1, StayDate) as 'MonthOfStay'
       ,DailyRateAmount
       ,SUM(DailyRateAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS [CummulativeRateAmt]
FROM Table1
WHERE ID = 625
AND StayDate between '2018-09-28' and '2018-09-30'
```

Output:

```
ID     StayDate     MonthOfStay  DailyRateAmt CummulativeRateAmt
625    2018-09-28   2018-09-01    100              300
625    2018-09-29   2018-09-01    100              300
625    2018-09-30   2018-09-01    100              300
```

I am looking for this output, with the `CummulativeRateAmt` column values showing the total rate amount for all the `StayDates` for each ID:

```
ID     StayDate     MonthOfStay  DailyRateAmt CummulativeRateAmt
625    2018-09-28   2018-09-01    100              400
625    2018-09-29   2018-09-01    100              400
625    2018-09-30   2018-09-01    100              400
```

I understand that I can nest the first query above and then filter on the `StayDates` after the nesting.

However, is there a partitioning syntax that will allow me to do it without having to nest my `T-SQL` query?

Comment: No `FROM tablename` needed?

Comment: The partition will operate on the underlying records after the `WHERE` clause has been applied, so a subquery might be your only option.

Comment: @jarlh Thanks for pointing this out. I missed that line when doing the copy operation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `CTE` or `Sub-query` and then filter the records

```
WITH CTE AS (
 SELECT ID
       ,StayDate
       ,Dateadd(day, -datepart(day,StayDate) + 1, StayDate) as 'MonthOfStay'
       ,DailyRateAmount
       ,SUM(DailyRateAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS [CummulativeRateAmt]
 FROM table t
 WHERE ID = 625
)

SELECT * FROM CTE 
WHERE StayDate between '2018-09-28' and '2018-09-30'
```

You could also do that via `CROSS JOIN` with filtered Id to get the total sum

```
SELECT  ID, StayDate,
        Dateadd(day, -datepart(day,StayDate) + 1, StayDate) as 'MonthOfStay',
        DailyRateAmount,
        tt.CummulativeRateAmt
FROM table t CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT SUM(DailyRateAmount) CummulativeRateAmt FROM table WHERE ID = 625) tt
WHERE ID = 625 AND
       StayDate between '2018-09-28' and '2018-09-30'
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I recommend the more explicit approaches using a CTE or subquery (it is easier to follow the intended logic), you can do what you want using `TOP WITH TIES`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES ID, StayDate,
       Dateadd(day, -datepart(day,StayDate) + 1, StayDate) as MonthOfStay,
       DailyRateAmount
       SUM(DailyRateAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS CumulativeRateAmt
FROM Table1
WHERE ID = 625
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN StayDate between '2018-09-28' and '2018-09-30' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END);
```